# Accessing Variables in Rails 3 before_save Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, before-save

I have the following `before_save` method:

```
def get_data
  url = "http://www.api-fetching-url.com/where_my_data_input_is=#{self.my_data}&output=json"
  new_data = HTTParty.get(url)
  @field_to_update = new_data['one']['two']['here']
  self.field_to_update = @field_to_update
end
```

Unfortunately, the `self.my_data` doesn't appear to be working, because the JSON url doesn't produce any result. But, when I substitute `my_data` in the hardcoded way, it works just fine. Moreover, I can do a `find` in the Rails console and get the `my_data` field just fine. So, it's not an issue with that field not saving or something on the form side.

Is there an issue inserting data this way in a `before_save` method? If not, is there a different way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post `my_data` method? I'm wondering if you are using this a class method correctly.

Comment: `my_data` is actually `self.start_date.month` in this case. The `start_date` is a field in the form and `def get_data` is a `before_save` in the model for that form submit.

Comment: Can you try `my_data` instead of `self.my_data`?

Comment: I tried it without and it doesn't work either... I think the self prefix is required when the method isn't prefixed itself.

Comment: Do you use my_data method as a class method or instance method? So for example, `Something.my_data` or `@something.my_data`?

Comment: I believe it's being used as a class method, since it's in the model class being referenced with `self`. But, the `my_data` field is submitted from a from view. I'm trying to access that variable in order to look up another one using the `before_save` method in the model class.

Comment: Justin, class method looks like `def self.foo`, instance method is `def bar`. Both can call `self`. In an instance method `self` gives you that instance, in a class method it just gives you the class.

Comment: Justin, there's nothing wrong with the code sample you've posted. It must be a problem with how or when you're calling the method. Would you please post your whole model? If you've got sensitive information in there just replace it with a constant, like `MY_SECRET_CODE`.

Comment: +1 to get the definition of `my_data` method

Comment: Have you tried to check, if you are getting any error before saving your model e.g; if `YourModel.valid? save else puts YourModel.errros`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks:

- You don't have to (and actually can't) always call methods with the `self` receiver. Private methods for example can only be called without an explicit receiver, so no `self.` for private methods...
- Why don't you inspect the url and check whether it is correct? Just add `puts url` after the line where you assign the url, run your program and check the output. Is the url correct?
- You probably use HTTParty not correctly: `HTTParty.get('...')` returns a response object and you probably have to parse the response's body properly.

An example for a JSON service:

```
url      = 'http://service.com/path/to/resource.json'
response = HTTParty.get url

data = JSON.parse(response.body)
# now you can use the data, e.g.
# bla = data['one']['foo']
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because it led me to the solution by correcting a number of errors. Ultimately, the largest error was in my formatting of the JSON URL, but I wouldn't have arrived at the solution without removing `self`, using `puts url`, and make other changes you mentioned. Thanks!